# How To Calculate Customer Lifetime Value

Tags: customer, laravel-framework

I'm trying to build a plugin to get customer order and customer lifetime value.

This is my code so far:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use HelpScoutApp\DynamicApp;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model;
$app = new DynamicApp('HELPSCOUT-SECRET-KEY');
if ($app->isSignatureValid())
{
  $customer = $app->getCustomer();
  $user     = $app->getUser();
  $convo    = $app->getConversation();

  $html = array();
  $html[] = 'Orders';
  $html[] = '';
  $settings = array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'magento',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'topsecret',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
  );
  // This is far more readable on newer versions of Illuminate (with PHP 5.4 and above)
  $connFactory = new \Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory(new Illuminate\Container\Container);
  $conn = $connFactory->make($settings);
  $resolver = new \Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolver();
  $resolver->addConnection('default', $conn);
  $resolver->setDefaultConnection('default');
  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setConnectionResolver($resolver);

  class Order extends Model {
    public $table = 'sales_flat_order'; 
    public $timestamps = false;
  }
  $orders = Order::whereIn('customer_email', $customer->getEmails())->orderBy('entity_id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
  foreach($orders as $order)
  {
    $html[] = '<li><a href="http://example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/'.$order->entity_id.'/" target="_blank">#'.$order->increment_id.'</a>, '.number_format($order->base_grand_total, 2).' '.$order->base_currency_code .'</li>';
  }
  $html[] = '</ul>';
  echo $app->getResponse($html);
}
else
{
  echo 'Invalid Request';
}
```

Orders are OK, I need to get customer lifetime from the `sales_flat_order` table. Any idea how to get this?

Comment: http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/calculating-lifetime-value-of-a-customer-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

A better way to accomplish what you are trying to do would be

```
//get any third party information you need
//customer = $app->getCustomer();

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

// Now you can run ANY Magento code you want

$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
//$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_email', $email);
$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $id);

foreach ($orderCollection as $_order)
{

}
```

See

- [Magento: Grab/Display Customer's Lifetime Sales Stats and Total Amount of Orders on Order View Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168137/magento-grab-display-customers-lifetime-sales-stats-and-total-amount-of-orders)
- [Run Magento Code Externally](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/run-magento-code-externally/)
- [How to get order list for logged in customer in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161664/how-to-get-order-list-for-logged-in-customer-in-magento)

Comment: only suggeted frinds:-SELECT DISTINCT customer_email, customer_firstname, customer_lastname,
SUM(subtotal_invoiced) AS Total
FROM `sales_flat_order` AS a
GROUP BY customer_email
ORDER BY SUM(subtotal_invoiced) DESC

Comment: If I use your aproach, the file should be inside magento root? The thing is that help scout require a secure server and my magento instance is not secure, no ssl. So I've build this app outside of magento, on a secure server and that's why I've used this aproach.

Comment: To get lifetime sales you can either use php to sum up all order or query the database to sum it up.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168137/magento-grab-display-customers-lifetime-sales-stats-and-total-amount-of-orders